# PHP MySQL select rows where date time value within the last n minutes

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select, range

I have a MySQL table that looks a little like this:

```
Timestamp           | Content
-----------------------------------------
2018-10-28 12:59:47 | "Some string"
2018-10-29 04:13:48 | "Some other string"
```

The `Timestamp` column is of the `datetime` type. Values are being created for insertion into the column using the PHP `date()` function. For example, `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

I'd like to use PHP to select all rows where the timestamp value is within the last n minutes.

I know how to select all rows where the date is a particular value. For example, the following will select all rows where the timestamp matches the current date/time:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Timestamp = '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "'");
```

How would I make a query to select all rows where the Timestamp value is within the last, say, 49 minutes ?

Comment: Additionally, try and stray away from concatenating any variables into your query (While this query isn't prone to SQL injection as there is no user input, you're better off following good cording standards). Learn about [*prepared statements*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](//php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](//php.net/mysqli) - [this article](//php.net/manual/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you choose. If you go with PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this query (There's no need to involve PHP date functions, when MySQL has them built in. See [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) for more info):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE Timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 49 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Will this select all dates within the last n minutes (for example, within 49 minutes will also select dates 48, 47, 46 ... minutes ago and so on), or will it select only dates that are n minutes ago from now?

Comment: This will select any rows within the last 49 minutes. (48, 47, 46 and so on...)

Comment: Sorry, the answer is yes it will, I wasn't paying attention to the `>` operand. Thanks!